# knockout.js modal binding value update

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I have the following code in this jsFiddle.

The problem I'm having is that my child items do not update properly.

I can Click "Edit User" with a problem and see the data changing, but when I attempt to add a note or even if I were to write an edit note function, the data does not bind properly

http://jsfiddle.net/jkuGU/10/

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: Users">
<li>
    <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>   
    <div data-bind="foreach: notes">
        <span data-bind="text: text"></span>
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.editNote">Edit Note</a>
    </div>
    <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.addNote">Add Note</a>
     <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.EditUser">Edit user</a>
</li>
</ul>

    <div id="userModal" data-bind="with: EditingUser" class="fade hjde modal">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
            <h3>
                Editing user</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <label>
                Name:</label>
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: Name, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
             <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
        </div>
    </div>

<div id="addJobNoteModal" data-bind="with: detailedNote" class="fade hjde modal">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
            <h3>
                Editing Note</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <label>
                Text:</label>
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: text, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
             <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</a>
        </div>
    </div>
​



function Note(text) {
    this.text = text;
}

var User = function(name) {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = ko.observable(name);
    this.notes = ko.observableArray([]);
}

var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.Users = ko.observableArray();

    self.EditingUser = ko.observable();
    self.detailedNote = ko.observable();
    self.EditUser = function(user) {
        self.EditingUser(user);
        $("#userModal").modal("show");
    };


    this.addNote = function(user) {
        var note= new Note("original")
        self.detailedNote(note);
        $("#addJobNoteModal").find('.btn-warning').click(function() {
            user.notes.push(note);
            $(this).unbind('click');
        });

        $("#addJobNoteModal").modal("show");
    }

    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        self.Users.push(new User('User ' + i));
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
        $("#addJobNoteModal").find('.btn-warning').click(function() {
```

To this:

```
        $("#addJobNoteModal").find('.btn-primary').click(function() {
```

You were targetting the wrong button :)

Comment: Nah, that's not what's happening.  My click event is happening... I can check with alerts.  The problem is that the data in the observable is not being updated.

Comment: assuming that I didn't mess that up in my real code ;), i'm still having trouble getting an edit binding to work as well...

Comment: @AdamLevitt http://jsfiddle.net/jkuGU/15/ - that code works for "Add note" and now I can see that "Edit note" has issues .. let me dig further.

Comment: When the new note is created, it seems that it calls on `disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved()`. Not sure why that happens.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem after all was that you must bind to "value:" not "text:" in a form input/textarea.

Comment: Doesn't explain why the click won't fire on the "Edit note" =S

Comment: In this example, I never added a modal or an actual event handler for editNote.  One thing to be aware of is that you have to bind the object into the observable before binding the event click handler.  This was a "gotcha" that I bumped into.